# Refer to table by id

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, reference

Is there a way to reference a table by id. Essentially, the table contains rows which pertain to one of many tables.

e.g. I need to reference tables `A` or `B` or `C` in table `D`'s rows so that I know which table to join on.

I assume that if there is no shorthand way to reference a table externally then the only option is to store the table's name.

Comment: What kind of query do you have in mind? Provide a complete test case for accurate advice.

Answer (score 2):

There is a "shorthand reference" for a table: the [object identifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) - the OID of the catalog table `pg_class`. Simple way to get it:

```
SELECT 'schema_name.tbl_name'::regclass
```

However, do **not** persist this in your user tables. OIDs of system tables are not stable across dump / restore cycles.

Also, plain SQL statements do not allow to parameterize table names. So you'll have to jump through hoops to use your idea in queries. Either [dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-sql) or multiple LEFT JOINs with `CASE` statements ... potentially expensive.